# how to appear form element only if there is no "%" sign in php

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a form with many form elements that are not allways populated with data, depending on type of product. If I want to print one row - record from mysql db, I want to avoid print column with empty container for data or if I put "%" sign in it. Does anyone has an idea how to do that? Examples are welcome!

Comment: What have you tried? What is your database model? Are the "empty" fields `NULL`?

Comment: What? Could you please rephrase?

Comment: You should add some more code because there are a hundred ways how to do that, but only some might be useful in your case.

Comment: What about just not getting blank values back from the database in the first place.

Comment: @Bracketworks fields are not null, table is myisam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check against null or a blank string to see if the column is empty and use `strpos` to see if '%' appears in it. Only print the column data if the conditions are satisfied:

```
<?php if (!is_null($row['column']) && $row['column'] != '' && false === strpos($row['column'], '%')) : ?>
    <?php echo $row['column']; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Or in raw php:

```
if (!is_null($row['column']) && $row['column'] != '' && false === strpos($row['column'], '%')) {
    echo $row['column'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($yourValue != '' && strpos($yourValue, '%') === FALSE)
{
  // print empty container
}
```

...but how do you handle the case where the original database value contains already `%` and therefore should be displayed (see Bracketworks's comment)?

Comment: maybe `strpos($yourValue, '%') >= 1` because otherwise you could only enter "%". And then you could also check if the rest is numeric
`$num = str_replace('%', '', $yourValue);
if(numeric($num)) {
//numeric
}
`

Comment: In the original question, nothing indicates that the "value" to display is supposed to be numeric. BTW in your first sentence, I don't understand why I could only **enter** '%'... Here we're checking if a value should be **displayed** (or not).

Comment: well you're right but did you ever see a not numeric value with "%" (abc%) ?

Comment: Yes, for example searched strings with "joker" characters, like *'%-machine'* or *'some%'*. Or simply some comment telling for example *'30% discount for this nice customer.'*

Comment: Yeah you are right maybe he isn't using it for numeric content.

Comment: input data is suppose to be some string with mixed text and numbers like weight of vehicle or capacity of fuel tank or part or serial number or type or model of some product or parts of building etc. some of data could be  and some have no sense for different types of products.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID = 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
      if ($value != "" && strpos($value, '%') === false) {
         //Do your output here...
      } 
   }
}
```